# Why is my css animation only playing when triggered on first instance? And not again on subsequent triggers?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a css animation (stitches) which is triggered with jQuery via a scrollTop function (essentially to trigger when a sticky element sticks, this is only way I could find to do this). But if I scroll back up (triggering jQuery to reset the css back to original) and then scroll down to trigger again, the animation does not play, just goes straight to it's end-frame (blank).

IDEALLY what I'd like to achieve:

The animation rests on it's first frame before being 'stuck', then once stuck, the animation plays once and ends on it's final (blank) frame. When the animation becomes 'un-stuck' again (whether from scrolling BACK UP or DOWN PAST it's 'sticky area' the animation plays in reverse and rests again on the first frame.

Can anyone help get me close to achieving this, or at least with my initial problem?

Link to codepen minimal (as possible) reproducible example:

https://codepen.io/noodlesontoast/pen/rXaxPK

I've tried various animation property settings combinations, can't find any that work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       var button = $(".her-panel"); //get offset of second div
       var offset = button.offset().top - 80; //check for top property
       $(function () {
           $(window).scroll(function () {
               if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
                   $(".her-stitch").css("animation-play-state","running");
                   $(".her-stitch").css("animation-fill-mode","forwards");
               } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < offset) {
                   $(".her-stitch").css("animation-play-state","paused");
                   $(".her-stitch").css("animation-fill-mode","none");
               } 
           });
       });
    });
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
         var button = $(".colour-song"); //get offset of second div
         var offset = button.offset().top - 80; //check for top property
         $(function () {
             $(window).scroll(function () {
                 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
                   $(".colour-song-stitch").css("animation-play-state","running");
                   $(".colour-song-stitch").css("animation-fill-mode","forwards");
                 } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < offset) {
                   $(".colour-song-stitch").css("animation-play-state","paused");
                   $(".colour-song-stitch").css("animation-fill-mode","none");
                 }
             });
         });
     });
```

```css
#collections-section {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 4000px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    }
    #collections-section .section-header {
      margin-bottom: calc(30px + 1%);
    }
    #collections-section .section-header .section-header-line {
      height: 1px;
      width: calc(100% - 80px);
      margin-left: 40px;
      margin-right: 40px;
      background-color: #b3b3b3;
    }
    #collections-section .section-header .section-header {
      padding-top: 22px;
      font: 600 14.5px basic-sans, sans-serif;
      margin-left: 40px;
    }
    #collections-section .feature-photo-container {
      max-width: 62%;
      min-width: 400px;
      height: 1200px;
      background-color: grey;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    #collections-section .feature-photo-container img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1200px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    #collections-section .collection-containers {
      width: calc(100% - 40px);
      position: relative;
    }
    #collections-section .collection-containers .panel-container-allow-sliding {
      width: calc(44%);
      min-width: calc(520px);
      position: absolute;
      height: 90%;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel {
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      top: 80px;
      background-color: #fad9d2;
      width: calc(100% - 100px);
      height: calc(340px - 100px);
      padding: 50px;
      margin-top: 80px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .attention-line {
      height: 2px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: #333333;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      h3 {
      width: auto;
      font: 200 2.6rem Ogg-Roman, serif;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      p {
      font: 200 1rem basic-sans, sans-serif;
      line-height: 27px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 13%;
      text-align: center;
      font: 600 14.5px basic-sans, sans-serif;
      height: 40px;
      width: 100px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container:hover
      > .highlight-box {
      height: 30px;
      top: -20%;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container
      .button-text {
      z-index: 10;
      color: #ff7883;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container
      .button-text
      span {
      color: #333333;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container
      .highlight-box {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: 96px;
      height: 15px;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 0;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.2s, top 0.2s;
      /* Safari */
      transition: height 0.2s, top 0.2s;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .stitch-animation {
      position: absolute;
      width: 75px;
      height: 75px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .stitch-animation
      .her-stitch,
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .stitch-animation
      .colour-song-stitch {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: white;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0 0 10px 0;
      width: 15.8px;
      height: 2.015px;
      opacity: 1;
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      animation-timing-function: steps(7);
      animation-play-state: paused;
      animation-fill-mode: none;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .stitch-animation
      .stitch-1 {
      animation-name: move-in-steps1;
      top: calc(0% + 6px);
      left: 0;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .stitch-animation
      .stitch-2 {
      animation-name: move-in-steps2;
      top: calc(20% + 6px);
      left: 20%;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .stitch-animation
      .stitch-3 {
      animation-name: move-in-steps3;
      top: calc(40% + 6px);
      left: 40%;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .stitch-animation
      .stitch-4 {
      animation-name: move-in-steps4;
      top: calc(60% + 6px);
      left: 60%;
    }
    #collections-section
      .collection-containers
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .stitch-animation
      .stitch-5 {
      animation-name: move-in-steps5;
      top: calc(80% + 6px);
      left: 80%;
    }
    @keyframes move-in-steps1 {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      16% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      33% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      49% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      66% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      81% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes move-in-steps2 {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      16% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      33% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      49% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      65% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      66% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      81% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes move-in-steps3 {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      16% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      33% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      48% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      49% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      66% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      81% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes move-in-steps4 {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      16% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      32% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      33% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      49% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      66% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      81% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes move-in-steps5 {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      15% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      16% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      33% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      49% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      66% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      81% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    #collections-section .her-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-start;
      margin-left: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 5%;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    #collections-section .her-container .panel-container-allow-sliding {
      left: 0;
    }
    #collections-section
      .her-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      p {
      width: 320px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .her-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .button-text {
      margin-right: -17px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .her-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container {
      right: 55px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .her-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container
      .highlight-box {
      left: 11px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .her-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .her-stitches {
      right: -20px;
      top: -22px;
    }
    #collections-section .colour-song-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-start;
      margin-right: 40px;
    }
    #collections-section .colour-song-container .panel-container-allow-sliding {
      right: 0;
    }
    #collections-section
      .colour-song-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      p {
      width: 360px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .colour-song-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .button-text {
      margin-right: -17px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .colour-song-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .colour-song-stitch {
      left: -20px;
      top: -20px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .colour-song-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container {
      right: 60px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .colour-song-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .link-box-container
      .highlight-box {
      right: -6.5px;
    }
    #collections-section
      .colour-song-container
      .panel-container-allow-sliding
      .info-panel
      .colour-song-stitches {
      left: -20px;
      top: -20px;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

```html
<head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <div id="collections-section">
    
        <div class="section-header">
          <div class="section-header-line">
          </div>
          <div class="section-header">Collections
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="collection-containers her-container">
          <div class="panel-container-allow-sliding">
            <div class="info-panel her-panel">
              <div class="attention-line">
              </div>
              <h3>Her.</h3>
              <p>Her feminine divinity draws me like a moth to the light, it has a
                 hold on my soul and I want to laugh and cry at the same time.</p>
              <a class="link-box-container" href="https://www.reddit.com">
                <div class="button-text">Explore More</div>
                <div class="highlight-box"></div>
              </a>
    
              <div class="stitch-animation her-stitches">
                <div class="her-stitch stitch-1"></div>
                <div class="her-stitch stitch-2"></div>
                <div class="her-stitch stitch-3"></div>
                <div class="her-stitch stitch-4"></div>
                <div class="her-stitch stitch-5"></div>
              </div>
    
    
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-photo-container">
            <img src="images/collection-her-hero.jpg" alt="Grey Dress With Frills">
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="collection-containers colour-song-container">
          <div class="panel-container-allow-sliding">
            <div class="info-panel colour-song">
              <div class="attention-line">
              </div>
              <h3>The Colour Song.</h3>
              <p>It is the lyrics to our childhood song, where colour is a feeling,
                 a flavour, knowing no bounds and there’s no such thing as a
                 mute button.</p>
              <a class="link-box-container" href="https://www.reddit.com">
                <div class="button-text">Explore More</div>
                <div class="highlight-box"></div>
              </a>
    
    
              <div class="stitch-animation colour-song-stitches">
                <div class="colour-song-stitch stitch-1"></div>
                <div class="colour-song-stitch stitch-2"></div>
                <div class="colour-song-stitch stitch-3"></div>
                <div class="colour-song-stitch stitch-4"></div>
                <div class="colour-song-stitch stitch-5"></div>
              </div>
    
    
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="feature-photo-container">
            <img src="images/collection-colour-song-hero.jpg" alt="Orange Dress With Frills">
          </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that CSS animations don't simply reset. There are multiple options that you can use to reset it, I have displayed the option of removing and re-adding the animating elements after each 'reset' below.

```
var holder = $('.her-stitches').html();
$('.her-stitches').html('').html(holder);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var button = $(".her-panel"); //get offset of second div
   var offset = button.offset().top - 80; //check for top property
   $(function () {
       $(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(window).scrollTop() >= offset) {
               $(".her-stitch").css("animation-play-state","running");
               $(".her-stitch").css("animation-fill-mode","forwards");
           } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < offset) {
               var holder = $('.her-stitches').html();
               $('.her-stitches').html('').html(holder);
               $(".her-stitch").css("animation-play-state","paused");
               $(".her-stitch").css("animation-fill-mode","none");
           } 
       });
   });
});
```

```css
#collections-section {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
#collections-section .section-header {
  margin-bottom: calc(30px + 1%);
}
#collections-section .section-header .section-header-line {
  height: 1px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#collections-section .section-header .section-header {
  padding-top: 22px;
  font: 600 14.5px basic-sans, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
#collections-section .feature-photo-container {
  max-width: 62%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: -1;
}
#collections-section .feature-photo-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#collections-section .collection-containers {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  position: relative;
}
#collections-section .collection-containers .panel-container-allow-sliding {
  width: calc(44%);
  min-width: calc(520px);
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 80px;
  background-color: #fad9d2;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(340px - 100px);
  padding: 50px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .attention-line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  h3 {
  width: auto;
  font: 200 2.6rem Ogg-Roman, serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  p {
  font: 200 1rem basic-sans, sans-serif;
  line-height: 27px;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 13%;
  text-align: center;
  font: 600 14.5px basic-sans, sans-serif;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container:hover
  > .highlight-box {
  height: 30px;
  top: -20%;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container
  .button-text {
  z-index: 10;
  color: #ff7883;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container
  .button-text
  span {
  color: #333333;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container
  .highlight-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 96px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s, top 0.2s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: height 0.2s, top 0.2s;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .stitch-animation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .stitch-animation
  .her-stitch,
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .stitch-animation
  .colour-song-stitch {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  width: 15.8px;
  height: 2.015px;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(7);
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .stitch-animation
  .stitch-1 {
  animation-name: move-in-steps1;
  top: calc(0% + 6px);
  left: 0;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .stitch-animation
  .stitch-2 {
  animation-name: move-in-steps2;
  top: calc(20% + 6px);
  left: 20%;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .stitch-animation
  .stitch-3 {
  animation-name: move-in-steps3;
  top: calc(40% + 6px);
  left: 40%;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .stitch-animation
  .stitch-4 {
  animation-name: move-in-steps4;
  top: calc(60% + 6px);
  left: 60%;
}
#collections-section
  .collection-containers
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .stitch-animation
  .stitch-5 {
  animation-name: move-in-steps5;
  top: calc(80% + 6px);
  left: 80%;
}
@keyframes move-in-steps1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  81% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes move-in-steps2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  81% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes move-in-steps3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  48% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  81% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes move-in-steps4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  32% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  81% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes move-in-steps5 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  15% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  81% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
#collections-section .her-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  z-index: 2;
}
#collections-section .her-container .panel-container-allow-sliding {
  left: 0;
}
#collections-section
  .her-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  p {
  width: 320px;
}
#collections-section
  .her-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .button-text {
  margin-right: -17px;
}
#collections-section
  .her-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container {
  right: 55px;
}
#collections-section
  .her-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container
  .highlight-box {
  left: 11px;
}
#collections-section
  .her-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .her-stitches {
  right: -20px;
  top: -22px;
}
#collections-section .colour-song-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
#collections-section .colour-song-container .panel-container-allow-sliding {
  right: 0;
}
#collections-section
  .colour-song-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  p {
  width: 360px;
}
#collections-section
  .colour-song-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .button-text {
  margin-right: -17px;
}
#collections-section
  .colour-song-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .colour-song-stitch {
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}
#collections-section
  .colour-song-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container {
  right: 60px;
}
#collections-section
  .colour-song-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .link-box-container
  .highlight-box {
  right: -6.5px;
}
#collections-section
  .colour-song-container
  .panel-container-allow-sliding
  .info-panel
  .colour-song-stitches {
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="collections-section">

    <div class="section-header">
      <div class="section-header-line">
      </div>
      <div class="section-header">Collections
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collection-containers her-container">
      <div class="panel-container-allow-sliding">
        <div class="info-panel her-panel">
          <div class="attention-line">
          </div>
          <h3>Her.</h3>
          <p>Her feminine divinity draws me like a moth to the light, it has a
             hold on my soul and I want to laugh and cry at the same time.</p>
          <a class="link-box-container" href="https://www.reddit.com">
            <div class="button-text">Explore More</div>
            <div class="highlight-box"></div>
          </a>

          <div class="stitch-animation her-stitches">
            <div class="her-stitch stitch-1"></div>
            <div class="her-stitch stitch-2"></div>
            <div class="her-stitch stitch-3"></div>
            <div class="her-stitch stitch-4"></div>
            <div class="her-stitch stitch-5"></div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-photo-container">
        <img src="images/collection-her-hero.jpg" alt="Grey Dress With Frills">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```